# Electrical conductance of NaCl solution

Tags: electrolysis

I'd like to ask whether EC of a salt solution of iodized table salt differs from that of uniodized and to what extent?

Comment: Too little to be noticed.

Comment: And what is the point of this question?

Answer (score 1):

## Is salt an electrolyte?

Common table salt (NaCl) is an electrolyte, and when this is dissolved in water to form salt water, it becomes sodium ions (Na+) and chloride ions (Cl-), each of which is a corpuscle that conducts electricity.

Let's go back to conductivity. Conductivity is an index of how easy it is for electricity to flow. In water, it is the ions that pass electricity from one to the next. This means that the more Na+ and Cl- contained in water the more electricity is carried, and the higher the conductivity.

## Here's a chart:

[image: Conductivity chart]
(Don't mind the *sugar water* side)

Source linked [here.](http://www.horiba.com/sg/application/material-property-characterization/water-analysis/water-quality-electrochemistry-instrumentation/ph-knowhow/the-basis-of-conductivity/ions-in-water-and-conductivity/)

Comment: If something is not clear enough, feel free to ask.